# PopupView always shows a white rectangle as background

Tags: javafx, gluon

```
.popup-view {
    -fx-background-color: red; // nothing happens here
}
.popup-view .scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: green; // nothing happens here
}
.popup-view .viewport {
    -fx-background-color: violet; // color is shown
    -fx-border-color: violet;
    -fx-background-radius: 7; // no affect
    -fx-border-radius: 7;
}
```

[image]

if i remove .viewport it just shows a white background without radius.

i want a popup-view with a certain color and radius for
that background - as violet for example. thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your `PopupView` control with [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/), you'll see that its `ScrollPane` has as style class `root-node`.

So your css should be something like this:

```
.popup-view > .root-node {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.popup-view > .root-node > .viewport {
    -fx-background-color: violet; 
    -fx-border-color: violet;
    -fx-background-radius: 7; 
    -fx-border-radius: 7;
}
```